# Apache Wicket 9.7.0 resource bundle naming issue

Tags: wicket

I'm aggregating JavaScript resources like this

```
getResourceBundles().addJavaScriptBundle(MyWicketApplication.class,
                "js_bundle.js",
                wicketJQuery,
                wicketAjax,
                JavascriptResources.RESOURCE_1.getReference(),
                JavascriptResources.RESOURCE_2.getReference(),
                JavascriptResources.RESOURCE_3.getReference(),
                JavascriptResources.RESOURCE_4.getReference(),
                JavascriptResources.RESOURCE_5.getReference(),
                JavascriptResources.RESOURCE_6.getReference(),
                JavascriptResources.RESOURCE_7.getReference(),
                JavascriptResources.RESOURCE_8.getReference());
```

What I get after a page is rendered is something like this

```
./wicket/resource/com.my.company.MyWicketApplication/js_bundle-ver-3CA0BF236223C36D08331F94E24FAAAE.js
```

I don't mind having the part

```
js_bundle-ver-3CA0BF236223C36D08331F94E24FAAAE.js
```

But how to hide / remove this part

```
./wicket/resource/com.my.company.MyWicketApplication
```

to something like this

```
/resources/js_bundle-ver-3CA0BF236223C36D08331F94E24FAAAE.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the result of `getResourceBundles().addJavaScriptBundle(...)` and mount it at specific path:

```
 JavaScriptReferenceHeaderItem jsrhi = getResourceBundles().addJavaScriptBundle(...);
 ResourceReference rr = jsrhi.getReference();
 webApplication.mountResource("some/path", rr);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but I hade to change JavascriptReferenceHeaderItem to ResourceReference and had to change addJavaScriptBundle(...) to addJavaScriptBundle(...).reference(). I.e

 ResourceReference jsrhi = getResourceBundles().addJavaScriptBundle(...).reference();